# JavaFx text resizing

Tags: javafx, font-size

What is the best way (in terms of performance) to resize a text proportionally to the size of its parent ? I want to make a undecorated window in which the text (which can span several lines) always use all the available size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it is the best way but using scale is working fine.

You just have to listen changes to the heightProperty and widthProperty of the parents in order to compute a scale factor and apply it to the component (Here a Text or a Label). This can be done with JavaFx magic binding too :)

So, there is no need to dynamically change the Font or something like that (and I think this would be a lot more slow than scale computation).